# Redirector service

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I’m planning an URL redirector service.
I want to listen for domains added by the users, check the URL for old paths and redirect the visitor to the right ones.

I was thinking about using App Engine (Java), but it seems as I can’t programmatically set customs domains. Is this info right?

Is there any Google Cloud service or set of services that I could use to accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you cannot programatically create custom domains in GAE.

Your best bet is to use a solution that provides an external IP address that isn't shared with other users - you can then accept all traffic and dispatch according to Host header.

You could do this using GCE (with or without LB) or GKE.

Comment: Thanks for the rely, but it seems to be too much of an effort. I've decided to drop GCS and go with Amazon. On Amazon, using the Route 53 API, I can do what I need.

Comment: I meant "reply", not "rely".